# About the typographical effectiveness of left aligned equations

Tags: typography

It seems to me that in mathematical works, the equations are usually center aligned and in physical works they are usually left aligned. I wonder if there is any typographical reason to do it either way or it is just a matter of preference.

I know that this isn't the perfect place to ask this but, as far as I know, it is probably the best place as many TeX users are interested in such questions.

Comment: This is a typographical tradition...

Comment: @SergeyBelyaev Yeah, I know. What I want to know is that if there is any advantage to either way. Maybe it is easier to read in some way or another